# How to Rewrite Function Using Context Bounds?

Tags: scala, typeclass

Given the following `Addable` type-class:

```
scala> trait Addable[A] {
     |   def add(x: A): A
     | }
defined trait Addable
```

I created an instance for `Int`:

```
scala> class AddInt(x: Int) extends Addable[Int] {
     |   override def add(y: Int) = x + y
     | }
defined class AddInt
```

Then, I created an implicit `AddInt`:

```
scala> implicit val addInt: AddInt = new AddInt(10)
addInt: AddInt = AddInt@1f010bf0
```

Lastly, I defined a generic function, `foo`:

```
scala> def foo[A](x: A)(implicit ev: Addable[A]): A = ev.add(x)
foo: [A](x: A)(implicit ev: Addable[A])A
```

Now, I can call it with the successful implicit resolution of `addInt`:

```
scala> foo(10)
res0: Int = 20
```

How can I define `foo` using the [context bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html) notation?

example:

`def foo[A : Addable]...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the method like you do in your own example:

```
def foo[A : Addable](x: A) = implicitly[Addable[A]].add(x)
```

Comment: `A : Addable` means that `A` is a class that implements Addable? If so, how can `x`, which gets passed to `add`, be of type Addable too?

Comment: `A` doesn't implement `Addable`, it just means that there's an `Addable` for this `A`, the implicit one you defined above `addInt`

Comment: `def foo[A: Addable]` is just syntax sugar for `def foo[A](implicit addable: Addable[A])`